# Derivative of this function (quadratic over quadratic)

Tags: calculus

$$K = \frac{-(\sigma^2 + 3\sigma + 2)}{\sigma^2 - 8\sigma +15}$$

How is this differentiated with respect to $\sigma$?

The answer is

$$\dfrac{dK}{d\sigma} = \frac{11\sigma^2 - 26\sigma -61}{(\sigma^2 - 8\sigma + 15)^2}$$

And the quotient rule is a very long process, I get the feeling there was a short method.

Comment: It's just the quotient rule. $(f/g)'={f'g-g'f\over g^2}$. Your comment about partial fractions leads me to say "the derivative, not the indefinite integral"...

Comment: That would be the quotient rule... partial fractions is an integration technique, not differentiation.

Comment: Er I meant quotient, I was tired

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know that rule

Answer (score 2):

The quotient rule is not too long...

$$\begin{align*}\frac {dK}{d\sigma} =& \frac {(-2\sigma-3)(\sigma^2-8\sigma+15)-(2\sigma-8)(-\sigma^2-3\sigma-2)}{(\sigma^2-8\sigma+15)^2}\\
=& \frac{-(2\sigma^3-13\sigma^2+14\sigma+45)+(2\sigma^3-2\sigma^2-12\sigma-16)}{(\sigma^2-8\sigma+15)^2}\\
=& \frac{11\sigma^2-26\sigma-61}{(\sigma^2-8\sigma+15)^2}\end{align*}$$
The squared denominator is a good clue that the book (or whatever reference you are using for the answer) used the quotient rule.

I don't see any shortcuts to this question, so if you are being asked to differentiate it you should be familiar with the quotient rule at this point.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: He could use so-called ''logarithmic differentiation''; but I don't think this would qualify as a ''shortcut''.

Comment: Actually, OP could've used a combination of the product rule and chain rule if he didn't remember how to differentiate a quotient...

Comment: Definitely true, although neither seems to be much of a "shortcut" (as you mentioned). Perhaps it's worth mentioning that the quotient rule is simply an application of the product rule and the chain rule? Although that's probably in the Wikipedia entry...

Answer (score 2):

The three comments below are not really shortcuts.  More like longcuts. Because $x$ is easier to type than $\sigma$, the variable has been changed. We show how to differentiate $\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-8x+15}$ and leave it to someone else to change the sign at the end.

$1$) We are being asked to divide $x^2+3x+2$ by $x^2-8x+15$. So divide. We get
$$\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-8x+15}=1+\frac{11x-13}{x^2-8x+15}.$$
The derivative of $1$ is $0$, so we want the derivative of
$$\frac{11x-13}{x^2-8x+15}.$$
The algebra of the Quotient Rule is definitely easier with a linear polynomial on top than if we use the Rule on the original expression.

$2$) If we want to practice partial fractions before they are needed for integration, we can simplify further. Note that $x^2-8x+15=(x-3)(x-5)$. The partial fractions process shows that 
$$\frac{11x-13}{x^2-8x+15}=-\frac{10}{x-3}+\frac{21}{x-5}.$$
Now differentiation is genuinely easy.

$3$) Logarithmic differentiation can be useful.  We will be deliberately sloppy, and not worry about the fact that $\log u$ is not defined when $u \le 0$.  One can show that negative $u$ in fact give no problem. The derivative of $\log|u|$ with respect to $u$ is $\frac{1}{u}$. Breaking up the interval so that we can deal with $\log$ properly gives the same derivative as the one we get if  we just heedlessly calculate. Let
$f(x)=\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-8x+15}$. Then 
$$\log f(x)=\log(x^2+3x+2)-\log(x^2-8x+15).$$
Differentiate. We get more or less instantly
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{2x+3}{x^2+3x+2}-\frac{2x-8}{x^2-8x+15}.\qquad (\ast)$$
If we have to "simplify" $(\ast)$ to the form $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials, the simplification will not be much fun.  But the expression $(\ast)$ is certainly pleasant enough if we just want to evaluate the derivative at a particular numerical value of $x$.

For complicated products/quotients, "logarithmic differentiation" can be, for certain purposes, much more efficient than conventional differentiation. However, if we want to find where the derivative vanishes, the advantage tends to evaporate.

Answer (score 1):

A fast way to find the Derivative of Quadratic over Quadratic:

$$  \bbox[20px,border:1px solid red]
{
y = \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{a'x^2+b'x+c'}\quad\Rightarrow\quad y'= \frac{\left| \begin{array}\\ a&b\\ a'&b'\\ \end{array}\right| \times x^2 + 2 \times \left|\begin{array} \\ a & c \\ a' & c' \end{array}\right|\times x + \left|\begin{array}\\ b & c \\ b' & c' \end{array}\right|}{V^2}
}
$$

For example:

$$
y=\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\,\Rightarrow\,y'=\frac{(2+2)x^2+2\times(3-1)x+(-6-2)}{V^2}=\frac{4x^2+4x-8}{V^2}
$$

Now your question: 
$$
y=\frac{-x^2-3x-2}{x^2-8x+15}\,\Rightarrow\,y'=\frac{(8+3)x^2+2\times(-15+2)x+(-45-16)}{(x^2-8x+15)^2}=\frac{11x^2-26x-61}{(x^2-8x+15)^2}
$$

It is faster than the regular method. Even you can do it in your head. It is just calculating a determinant of a matrix. $\left| \begin{array}\\ a&b\\ a'&b'\\ \end{array}\right| = (a\times b')-(a'\times b)$

Comment: This is a practically useful formula. Did you perhaps find it in a reference with other similar formulas, and if so could you point me in the direction of that reference? It might be nice to have a good handbook of differentiation formulas to aid in the odd computation

Answer (score 0):

I'll set $\sigma = x,$ so that $K$ becomes $$-\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-8x+15}.$$

We reduce the problem as follows:

$$K=-\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-8x+15}=-\frac{x^2-8x+8x+3x+2+15-15}{x^2-8x+15}=-\frac{x^2+8x+15+11x-13}{x^2-8x+15}=-1+\frac{13-11x}{x^2-8x+15}=-1+\frac{13}{x^2-8x+15}-\frac{11x}{x^2-8x+15}.$$

Taking derivatives, the first term vanishes; the second term is also easy to deal with since we have that $(1/y)'=-y'/y^2,$ with $y$ being a function of $x.$ If you're not interested in the derivative for $x=0,$ we may reduce the problem even further by transforming the third summand to become $$-\frac{11}{x-8+15/x},$$ whose derivative is also easily computed, as before.